# Getting null when uploading a local file from nodejs to a Laravel server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel

I am trying to upload a local file using NodeJs *(the file is in the same directory as app.js)* to a remote Laravel server but I'm getting null. For some reason the file doesn't seem to get to the server. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Here is my node app folder structure

```
node_app/
├── node_modules/
├── app.js
├── screenshot.jpg
├── package.json
```

Here is my **app.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data')
const screenshot = require('screenshot-desktop')

let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('screenshot-file', fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'screenshot.jpg')))

axios.post(
  `https://www.myapp.com/api/upload-screenshot`,
  formData,
  { headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
)
```

And here is my Laravel endpoint

```
class ScreenshotController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        // $file is null :(
        $file = $request->file('screenshot-file');

        $filename = 'screenshot.jpg';
        $file->move(storage_path('/uploads/screenshots/'), $filename);

        return $filename;
    }
}
```

> Error: 'Call to a member function move() on null'

When the request arrives at my Laravel endpoint, there doesn't seem to be a 'screenshot-file' file submitted as it is showing null.

Also using `dump($request->all());` it returns an empty array [] which means nothing has been submitted.

However doing a simple post request, it does arrive at the server

```
axios.post(`https://www.myapp.com/api/upload-screenshot`, {
   hello: 'asdf'
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't the header be "Enctype" ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work after thoroughly reading the documentation for the node.js `form-data` library. So I will share it with others who might also run into this problem.

I was passing in the wrong headers, I needed to first get the headers from my formData object and then pass them on to axios like this:

```
function uploadScreenshot()
{
    let formData = new FormData()
    let stream   = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, 'screenshot.jpg'))

    formData.append('screenshot-file', stream)

    let formHeaders = formData.getHeaders()

    axios.post('https://www.myapp.com/api/upload-screenshot', formData, {
        headers: {
            ...formHeaders,
        },
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```